# I want to update data to my database using PDO but nothing changes in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
        extract($_POST);
        if($eventName ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the Event Name.';
    }
        if(!isset($error)){
            try {
                $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE event SET eventID = :eventID, eventName = :eventName, eventTime = :eventTime, eventLocation = :eventLocation, postDate = :postDate WHERE eventID = :eventID') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                ':eventID' => $eventID,
                    ':eventName' => $eventName,
            ':eventTime' => $eventTime,
            ':eventLocation' => $eventLocation,
            ':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                ));
                //redirect to index page
                header('Location: view-event.php?action=updated');
                exit;
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

And

```
<?php
        //check for any errors
        if(isset($error)){
            foreach($error as $error){
                echo $error.'<br />';
            }
        }
            try {
                $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT eventID,eventName, eventTime, eventLocation, postDate FROM event WHERE eventID = :eventID') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(':eventID' => $_GET['eventID']));
                $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>
```

HTML Form

```
<form role="form" method="post" action=''>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Event Name" name="eventID" value='<?php echo $row['eventID'];?>'>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Event Name" name="eventName" value='<?php echo $row['eventName'];?>'>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Event Time" name="eventTime" value='<?php echo $row['eventTime'];?>'>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Event Location" name="eventLocation" value='<?php echo $row['eventLocation'];?>'>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Edit Event">
</form>
```

Hi,
Here is the code. I want to update data to mysql database. When I hit the button it just loaded to "view-event.php?action=updated" this page but nothing changes in database. Please help me.

Comment: Why is there an `action=updated`? you are not accessing any GET data in your code... Post your form's HTML code

Comment: Not like this. Put your form code in your question.

Comment: Put this on top of your page and tell us if you now see any errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: hello @aendeerei there is no error code. but updation to database is not working.

Comment: @MehdiBounya I already update html code to question.

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST)` and **update your question** with the result, do you get any output after submitting the form?

Comment: @aendeerei have you said about $stmt?

Comment: @MehdiBounya not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working? post var_dump's result...

Comment: Its redirecting to view-event.php?action=updated but nothing changes in mysql

Comment: @aendeerei I already updated first input name. but still not working

Comment: Ah, ok. Then please give us the create table syntax, so that we can test too.

Comment: Arnab, we are waiting for the statement `CREATE TABLE event ...` from you.

Comment: Are you emulating prepared queries in the connection?

Comment: I like that you're using PDO, that shows you're trying to do things right, but what is `stripslashes` doing here? That just damages data. The primary reason that function exists is to deal with the garbage "magic quotes" create, a feature that's been removed from PHP entirely because of what a spectacularly bad idea it was.

Comment: My money is on updating `SET eventID = :eventID`, and `WHERE eventID = :eventID`, with emulation on with only one bound param, which wont work. also if you pass in a different id :/ You should also avoid doing `extract($_POST);`.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone In my tests you've earned a lot of money! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finished my tests without the create table santax. If it still doesn't work, then it has to do with the table definition.

Unless you want to do something else with the caught exceptions, other than displaying an error message to the user, you should remove the *try-catch* blocks. It will allow you to show a user-friendly error message/page in the future, by means of defining an [error](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and an [exception handler](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php). While in the meantime PHP will just show you the error message and die: exactly what you need during the development. Take a look into [this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) and [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) tutorial chapters in order to see how to apply the error and exception handling and reporting.

In the update statement you are using the `:eventID` marker twice, but assigning the value of `$eventID` once. In order to be able to do this you need to activate emulation, as part of the connection options. If you don't do this you are receiving the exception

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
```

So, put this in your connection options array:

```
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => TRUE
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @aendeerei it works now.

pardon i didn't notice that you asked me the syntax.

Comment: @ArnabDasguptaADG What, I asked you five time at least :-))))) I am joking, Arnab ;-) You are welcome. Read the tutorial, it's awesome.

Comment: using exit is a terrible idea. as well as echoing the error message in the catch block

Comment: Thanks @YourCommonSense. Your note on echoing is welcomed. That's why I directed Arnab to... your tutorial. Regarding _exit_, why is a terrible idea? Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Indeed. But now I'm confused of what you say: Isn't a PDO exception (one not catched on purpose, for special purposes) the case in which an exception handler should catch it, display a user-friendly error message/page and exit? I mean: should the page workflow really be permitted to perform upon such an exception? Like by displaying a user-friendly error message in a messages div, above the form? I would say no: a separate error page should be shown. What do you think?

Comment: Yes it is. That's why catching exceptions like you did is a terrible practice - it will prevent such a graceful handling. You should have told the OP to remove try and catch instead

Comment: @YourCommonSense I got your point now. I did give a wrong advise to the OP indeed. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you too. Your edit is welcome and good. Have a nice day.

Comment: @ArnabDasguptaADG I did gave you a wrong advise earlier. My bad! Though, thanks to the correct observations of YourCommonSense, the answer is now in the proper form. You might want to read it again. Good luck.